# Problem joining two python scripts + QMessageBox + Chi-square + vector tools

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I created a model that combines two vector layers and outputs a single layer with aggregated data, after that, is calculated chi-square test. I tried join both, but I can´t. Now, when it´s executed, it crashes QGIS. Could someone look it?

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Aleatorio
Group : Vector
With QGIS : 33401
"""

# abrir script que executa vetor e estatística (R ou Py)


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from qgis.core import QgsProject  # Certifique-se de ter a importação correta
from qgis.gui import QgsFieldComboBox, QgsDoubleSpinBox
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QMessageBox
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsExpression, QgsExpressionContext, QgsExpressionContextUtils
from qgis.gui import QgsExpressionBuilderDialog #será usado depois
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
                       QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chisquare, norm
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class Aleatorio(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
# (def initAlgorithm)
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('camada_a_ser_analisada_pontos', 'Camada a ser analisada (pontos)', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('define_a_largura_da_área_de_estudo_no_entorno_dos_pontos', 'Define a largura da área de estudo no entorno dos pontos', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, defaultValue=1000))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('driver__candidato_polígono', 'Driver - candidato (polígono)', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('valor_do_ajuste_da_area_aos_pontos_entre_0_e_1', 'Valor do ajuste da área aos pontos (entre 0 e 1)', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, maxValue=1, defaultValue=0.3))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('campo_agrupamento', 'Campo de Agrupamento', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any, parentLayerParameterName='driver__candidato_polígono'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Dados_sistematizados', 'Dados Sistematizados', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('results', 'results', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('define_o_valor_de_alpha', 'Define o valor de alpha para o teste Chi-square', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, defaultValue=0.05))

    # exibir a caixa de diálogo e salvar o arquivo HTML
    # vers]ao melhorzinha até agora
    @staticmethod
    def exibir_caixa_dialogo_e_salvar_html(mensagem):
        # Exibir a mensagem em uma caixa de diálogo
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Resultado do Teste Qui-Quadrado")
        msg_box.setText(mensagem)
        msg_box.exec_()

        # Pedir ao usuário para escolher o local de salvamento do arquivo HTML
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Salvar Resultados", "", "Arquivos HTML (*.html);;Todos os Arquivos (*)", options=options)

        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    file.write("<html><body>\n")
                    file.write("<pre>\n")
                    file.write(mensagem)
                    file.write("</pre>\n")
                    file.write("</body></html>\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Erro ao salvar arquivo HTML: {e}")


    # executa as funções
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use QgsExpressionBuilderDialog para obter o campo de agrupamento dinamicamente
        campo_agrupamento = self.parameterAsString(parameters, 'campo_agrupamento', context)
        if not campo_agrupamento:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Erro", "Seleção de campo de agrupamento cancelada.")
            return {}
            
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(9, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Concave hull
        alg_params = {
            'ALPHA': parameters['valor_do_ajuste_da_area_aos_pontos_entre_0_e_1'],
            'HOLES': True,
            'INPUT': parameters['camada_a_ser_analisada_pontos'], # o input do concave é a camada vetorial de pontos
            'NO_MULTIGEOMETRY': False,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ConcaveHull'] = processing.run('native:concavehull', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
      
        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Buffer
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': True,
            'DISTANCE': parameters['define_a_largura_da_área_de_estudo_no_entorno_dos_pontos'],
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'INPUT': outputs['ConcaveHull']['OUTPUT'], # o input do buffer é o cancave, então fica: 
            # 'INPUT': dicionario de outputs['camada do dicionario a ser utilizada']['nome da saída da função']
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'SEPARATE_DISJOINT': False,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Buffer'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Clip
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['driver__candidato_polígono'],
            'OVERLAY': outputs['Buffer']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ClipCortaCamadaDrivePeloBufferDaCamadaPontual'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        #  aggregate
        alg_params = {
            'AGGREGATES': [{'aggregate': 'concatenate_unique', 'delimiter': ',', 'input': f'"{campo_agrupamento}"', 'length': 250,
                            'name': campo_agrupamento, 'precision': 0, 'sub_type': 0, 'type': 10, 'type_name': 'text'}],
            'GROUP_BY': f'"{campo_agrupamento}"',
            'INPUT': outputs['ClipCortaCamadaDrivePeloBufferDaCamadaPontual']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Aggregate'] = processing.run('native:aggregate', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
 
        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator area
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 2,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 2,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Decimal (double)
            'FORMULA': '$area/sum($area)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Aggregate']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculatorAreaporc'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Count points in polygon
        alg_params = {
            'CLASSFIELD': '',
            'FIELD': 'NUMPOINTS',
            'POINTS': parameters['camada_a_ser_analisada_pontos'],
            'POLYGONS': outputs['FieldCalculatorAreaporc']['OUTPUT'],
            'WEIGHT': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['CountPointsInPolygon'] = processing.run('native:countpointsinpolygon', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator (esperado)
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 2,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'esperado',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 2,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Decimal (double)
            'FORMULA': 'round($area/sum($area)+($area/sum($area)*(1-sum("area"))),3)',
            'INPUT': outputs['CountPointsInPolygon']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculatorEsperadoAjuste1'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator (observado)
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 2,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'observado',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 2,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Decimal (double)
            'FORMULA': 'round("NUMPOINTS"/sum("NUMPOINTS"),3)',
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculatorEsperadoAjuste1']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            #'OUTPUT': parameters['Dados_sistematizados']
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculatorObservado'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
 
        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        # Chi-square     
        camada_resultante, mensagem_resultante = self.qui_quadrado_aderencia_qgis(
            camada=outputs['FieldCalculatorObservado']['OUTPUT'],
            alfa=self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, 'define_o_valor_de_alpha', context),
            campo_esperado='esperado',
            campo_observado='observado'
        )

        # caixa de diálogo e o arquivo HTML
        self.exibir_caixa_dialogo_e_salvar_html(mensagem_resultante)

        # Retornar a camada resultante
        outputs['CamadaResultante'] = {'OUTPUT': camada_resultante}

        return outputs
    
    def calcular_valores_criticos(self, alfa_corrigido):
        # Calcular os valores críticos da distribuição normal padrão
        limite_superior = norm.ppf(1 - alfa_corrigido / 2)
        limite_inferior = norm.ppf(alfa_corrigido / 2)
        return limite_superior, limite_inferior

    def qui_quadrado_aderencia_qgis(self, camada, alfa, campo_esperado='esperado', campo_observado='observado'):
        # Verificar se 'camada' é uma string antes de acessar as features
        if isinstance(camada, str):
            print("Erro: A camada não é válida. Verifique se a camada foi criada corretamente.")
            return None, "Erro: A camada não é válida. Verifique se a camada foi criada corretamente."
    
        valores_esperados = []
        valores_observados = []

        for feature in camada.getFeatures():
            valor_esperado = feature[campo_esperado]
            valor_observado = feature[campo_observado]
            if isinstance(valor_esperado, (int, float)) and isinstance(valor_observado, (int, float)):
                valores_esperados.append(float(valor_esperado))
                valores_observados.append(float(valor_observado))

        chi2, p_valor = chisquare(valores_observados, f_exp=valores_esperados)
        res_padronizados = (np.array(valores_observados) - np.array(valores_esperados)) / np.sqrt(valores_esperados)

        p_valor_corrigido = p_valor * len(valores_esperados)
        alfa_corrigido = alfa / len(valores_esperados)

        limite_superior, limite_inferior = self.calcular_valores_criticos(alfa_corrigido)

        mensagem = "Estatística qui-quadrado: {}\n".format(chi2)
        mensagem += "Valor-p: {}\n".format(p_valor)
        mensagem += "Valor-p corrigido (Bonferroni): {}\n".format(p_valor_corrigido)
        mensagem += "Resíduos Padronizados:\n{}\n".format(res_padronizados)
        mensagem += "Valores críticos para alfa corrigido ({}):\n".format(alfa_corrigido)
        mensagem += "Limite Superior: {}\n".format(limite_superior)
        mensagem += "Limite Inferior: {}\n".format(limite_inferior)

        if p_valor_corrigido < alfa_corrigido:
            mensagem += "Rejeitar a hipótese nula: A distribuição do fenômeno analisado não possui carácter aleatório (com correção de Bonferroni)."
        else:
            mensagem += "Falha em rejeitar a hipótese nula: A distribuição do fenômeno analisado possui carácter aleatório (com correção de Bonferroni)."

        # Retorna a camada e as mensagens
        return camada, mensagem

    def name(self):
        return 'Aleatorio'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Aleatorio'

    def group(self):
        return 'Vector'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Vector'

    def createInstance(self):
        return Aleatorio()
```

Comment: Within a processing algorithm it is not possible to use QFileDialog or other Qt dialogs like QMessageBox(). This will cause a crash!

Comment: Are you trying to create a plugin?

Comment: For the html save path, add it as a parameter in `initAlgorithm()`. For messages, use `feedback.pushInfo()` or `feedback.reportError()`